# How can I cut the end of the text of a label with HTML format

Tags: html, xaml, xamarin.forms, label, truncation

I verified in some tests that just using `TextType` as `Text`, I can cut the text from a label at the end.

I wonder if there is any way to accomplish this in text in HTML format.

```xml
<Label Text="{Binding message}"
       TextType="Html"
       LineBreakMode="TailTruncation"
       HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
       Style="{StaticResource LabelStyle}"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could binding the text with html string like below.

```
 public string message { get; set; }
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        message = "This is <strong>HTML</strong> text.";

        this.BindingContext = this;
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Got it. The problem is that this text is sent from a form in another part of the system, where the person can send it with HTML or without. So I had left it as the default HTML type